# Lightning produces antimatter -- does an h-bomb?

Tags: antimatter, fusion

When I search on this, I get hits for antimatter weapons but I am wondering if very energetic events like an h-bomb or a fission weapon are know to produce antimatter? If so, could it be produced in a fusion reactor?

Comment: Have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter . positrons are the antiparticles of electrons and can be produced in quantum interactions, if there is enough energy. Fusion has much more that the one MEV  for the creation of a pair  e+e-, but if you are thinking of using this antimatter, it is no good. To separate it from the mess would be technologically impossible. see this to understand the high technology needed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiproton_Accumulator

Comment: @annav I was not thinking of using this antimatter -- asking for a friend. Sounds like antimatter is indeed being produced however. The way I would get antimatter is scooping it from I think the upper reaches of Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: scooping it would need high technology, because all our scoops are with matter, and antimatter annihilates when  meeting matter, which happens for all antimatter produced in our atmosphere whatever way, as  earth is made of matter

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, any event that creates gamma ray photons with energies of 1 MeV or higher can create antimatter, because a sufficiently high energy gamma ray photon can decay into an electron-positron pair. It is believed that a small number of electron-positron pairs are created in this way as a result of the high voltage electrical discharges in thunderstorms. Positrons are also naturally produced in some radioactive decay chains (which is how they are created in [positron emission tomography](https://Positron%20emission%20tomography)) and about 1% of cosmic rays are antimatter particles.

The problem with harvesting naturally occurring antimatter from the Earth's atmosphere is that an antimatter particle such as a positron will be annihilated as soon as it comes into contact with an atom of ordinary matter. Which means that any antimatter in the Earth's atmosphere has an *extremely* short lifetime. Similarly, any antimatter particles created in a fusion reactor will be annihilated almost immediately.

Artificially produced antiparticles can have their lifetimes extended because (a) they are created in a very pure vacuum and (b) they are isolated and confined by a combination of electric and magnetic fields in a device called a [Penning trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap).

Comment: Agreed that *producing* antimatter is a much more pedestrian task than *harvesting* antimatter. When I was in grad school I sat down and figured out how much antimatter there is in a banana. (One positron roughly every 75 minutes.)